# jQuery after ul list .remove() won't fill list again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

When the page is loaded, there are 3 lists. First containing an active list and second and third are blank. When clicked on the active list li the second list (ul) is filled with one li element, the filling process continues to the third list automatically (on mouse click). Then when the button delete is pressed, both lists get removed and the process is supposed to work the same as described, but the second list for some reason doesn't get filled and everything goes to the third list.

I have tried methods: remove(), empty(), detach() but none of them seem to work.
Also in if statement I tried to check `if (typeof ul.lenght === "undefined")` but even this is not working.

Also to mention in `console.log()` when cheking ul.lenght property first time it returns 0 and undefined and fill the second list but after delete button is pressed it returns same value but won't fill the list.

Here is the code:

```
function myf() {
    var orig = $("#ori li").length;
    if ($("#ori li").length === 0 || typeof orig === "undefined") {
        $(document).on('click', '#orglis li', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $("#ori").append(this);
        });
    } else {
        $(document).on('click', '#orglis li', function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $("#zam").append(this);
            var lio = document.getElementById("ori").getElementsByTagName("li");
            var larr = lio[0].innerText;
            var arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#c>ul>li'), li => (li.textContent));
            var tekst = "";
            var i;
            var j;
            for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j].trim();
            }
            for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                tekst += larr + ", " + arr[i] + '\n';
            }

            document.getElementById("tare").innerHTML = tekst;
            document.getElementById("imep").value = larr;
        });
    }
}
```

**[Here](http://develoope.me/dnd2/)** you can see demo.

EDIT: Also tried with outerHTML to set ul as before but still won't work

Comment: Some slightly confusing code here.   You're mixing `onclick=` with `$(document).on("click", ` which will always cause confusion.  How often do you call `myf()`?  Just once at start up?  Looks like every time you click "#ori" - so everytime you click you add a *new event handler* for the `li` click?  That's clearly not right.  Just add your event handlers in doc.ready and handle it inside - ie check *inside* the `#orglis li` click event where it should go.

Comment: `$("#ori").append(this);` will *move* `this` to `#ori`, there's no need for `$(this).remove()`

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't know but if I remove either of that the code won't work only work if it is together on click and click event, maybe I'm doing osmething wrong

Answer (score 0):

@freedomn-m was right about mixing `onclick=` and `$(document).on("click"` and I noticed that I had, without reason, two same functions